# Redirects based on a JSON file

Tags: functions, redirect, json

Having a JSON file, how can we set up WordPress to redirect the urls (if it's found in the JSON file)?

For example:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo-1": "baz"
}
```

Then `/foo` will redirect to `/bar` and `/foo-1` to `/baz`.

What's the best way to do this?
Currently I do it with `rewrite_rule` in `functions.php`, but each time the redirects change, I have to save the Permalinks Settings.

The redirects in `functions.php` are handled like this:

```
function handle_book_redirects() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^(foo|foo-1)$',
    'index.php?myVar=redirect:$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'handle_book_redirects' );
```

Then if `myVar` is appended and it's a redirect, a custom php will handle that request.

Comment: why json make any difference? what is you code that you use to redirect?

Comment: WordPress use a cache to save ressources when doing the URL Rewriting. then you need to flush the permalinks every time the redirections change

Comment: @mmm How can I trigger the flush from another separated app (which generates the redirects json file)?

Comment: @MarkKaplun Because I want to make it dynamic. Currently I have to add the redirect urls in two places: in my php file and in `functions.php` (added in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it. Note there may be a more straightforward way.

#### Step 1

Add a custom `query_var`like this to record the redirect from/to variables

```
function my_custom_query_vars($vars){
     //this allows you to store custom variables with rediect_from and rediect_to in the url
     $vars[] = 'redirect_from';
     $vars[] = 'redirect_to';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars' );
```

#### Step 2

Add `foreach` loop that does something like this. This will add the rewrite rules to change `http://example.com/foo` to `http://example.com/?redirect_from=foo&redirect_to=bar`

```
function my_custom_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
    $new_rules = array();
    $json = '';//get your json data and store it as this string
    $json_array = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach($json_array as $key => $value){
        $new_rules['^'.$key.'$'] = 'index.php/?redirect_from='.$key.'&redirect_to='.$value;
    }
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

#### Step 3

Hook into the `parse_request` filter to parse your request and redirect as necessary.

```
 function my_custom_parse_request($wp){
//we make sure the keys are present and not empty before we redirect
if ((array_key_exists('redirect_from', $wp->query_vars) 
    && !empty($wp->query_vars['redirect_from']))
    && (array_key_exists('redirect_to', $wp->query_vars)
    && !empty($wp->query_vars['redirect_to']))){
        wp_redirect(home_url('/'.$wp->query_vars['redirect_to']));
        exit;        
}
add_action('parse_request', 'my_custom_parse_request');
```

Comment: What happens when the JSON file is changed? How can I do it that will trigger an event and will reload the json string? I don't want to read the json file and parse it on every request, but load it in memory and reload it when it's changed.

Comment: I'd suggest you save the json string as an option in the `wp_options` table using the `optionsAPI`. You would then load the json string in the function using `get_optiom()`. All you'll have to do is update the settings whenever the json file changes. If the json file is not external, you could add a custom hook to re-save the function whenever it changes

Comment: Is `my_custom_rewrite_rules` called when flushing the permalinks? I think I will use the `WP_Rewrite::wp_rewrite_rules()` method to reload the json.

Comment: The code I gave should be put either in the `functions.php` of your child theme or in a plugin. I have been using the method in a couple sites and it works flawlessly

Comment: Shouldn't `wp->` be `$wp->`? Also, the `$wp` variable is `undefined`... I'm not a php expert...

Comment: You're correct. Sorry. I made a mistake and forgot the first line of the function. I've corrected it now though

Comment: This seems to have an issue: I have `foo` which redirects to `foo-42`—and this enters into an infinite loop.

Comment: I can't know where it is coming from without running the code. Try to change `foo-42` to `foo_42`, check to see if `foo-42` is among the keys in the json file. just help find why it's happening.

Comment: It was because we should use `^` and `$` to match the urls.  It's working now nicely. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest the edit?